# XMLHttpRequest over SSL doesn't return any data

Tags: ajax, ssl, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest over SSL for a login system.  Currently, I'm just testing the capabilities of XMLHttpRequest over SSL to make sure it indeed works.  So here's what I'm testing:

Relevant Javascript:

```
xml_request.open("POST", "https://......", true);

xml_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 0);
xml_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xml_request.send();

alert(xml_request.reponseText); //displayed using the appropriate onreadystatechange handler
```

PHP Script:

```
print json_encode(array(
  "text" => "this is text"
));
```

Now, using http the request works fine; xml_request.responseText holds the JSON encoded string.  When I use https, xml_request.responseText is defined, but it's an empty string.

Does anyone why this is and/or how to fix this?

Thanks much,
Dale

Comment: Just to check, have you tried to make such a query directly (without XmlHttpRequsest), perhaps using a tool like `curl` to see whether the request works at all? Do you make the request to your HTTPS site from a page served over HTTPS on the same site, or from a page served over plain HTTP (in which case you'd be limited by the cross-site restrictions)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, any certificate mismatch will prevent you from connecting. Can you open the site URL with a browser and check for the certificate settings on the server to see if anything is out of the ordinary or giving you warning messages?

Comment: I connected to the page via https and no errors came up.  I have already confirmed a security exception in Firefox since this is a self-signed certificate on my testing server...

Comment: Based on the FF exception I'd say that we're on the right track assuming it might be a certificate issue. Can you check if the client cert is correctly installed on both the machine and user keychains?